# MYSQL python job adding data too often

Tags: python, mysql

Insert2.py runs as scheduled, writing Pimoroni enviro phat data to mysql.
dallas321.py however writes data to mysql every two seconds - way too often.

dallas321 is writing the exact same data as insert2.py, with the addition of two DS18B20 temp sensors.

Both jobs work OK, in that they are writing to the db OK.

```
*/2 * * * * /usr/bin/python /home/pi/sql_insert2.py

#*/2 * * * * /usr/bin/python /home/pi/dallas321.py
```

Comment: In what file is the cron-job created in? Is it possible that there is a second file that is executing the file?

Comment: They're both in /home/pi. Anything's possible I guess, but the *dallas* job is new, nothing else touches it.

Comment: I just tried running them manually - *sudo python jobname.py* and got the exact same results. One runs, inserts data and stops, the other inserts data every second until it's stopped manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed.

Problem was a missing/lost/deleted `break` at the end of a `While True:`